# permissions for backup operators to eject disks

Tags: backup, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, hard-drive

I'm backing up a Windows Server 2008 R2 server to external USB disks using Windows Server backup.  I want the person who physically removes the drive to rotate it offsite to be able to eject the drive before unplugging it.  How should I set up my permissions for this?  I tried adding them to the "Backup Operators" group but it just prompts them for an admin password when they try to eject it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check the security option "Devices: Allowed to format and eject removable media". You can configure that via (Local) Group Policy. Run gpedit.msc and navigate to:

Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options

Set the option to "Administrators and Interactive Users".

Comment: Thank you, I've done this but it doesn't seem to have worked. The user is still being prompted for an admin account when ejecting the drive. Does the server need to be rebooted for it to take effect?